# Does transit in Lima airport requires checking out?

Tags: visas, transit, peru, bolivia, ecuador

I am in a situation where I booked my flight from Europe to Peru and where I am stuck in the visa process because of a missing document that will apparently still take some time to be ready. I am starting to consider an alternative to Peru in case I don't get the visa in time. I am a Tunisian citizen living in Germany and the embassy here says it takes 6 weeks to issue a tourist visa (I fly in 4 weeks). Next to Peru, there are Brazil and Ecuador, countries for which I don't need visas.

If a book a ticket from Lima (where I land in Peru) to Quito for example, will I be able to board from Europe by showing them that I directly fly to Quito after landing in Peru? Is a direct transfer to Lima airport possible (like in the European airports).

The logic behind that is that I already booked the flight for Peru so if I don't get the visa in time, it would be a big waste of money. So investing a bit more in an additional ticket from Peru to Ecuador for example and visiting Ecuador instead would be a solution.

I am also applying for a Bolivian visa in the mean-time, because I plan to visit it as well. Would it be possible to fly to Bolivia from Lima directly and apply for the Peruvian visa there?

Comment: What is the actual destination of your trip? It sounds like you're planning merely to _transit_ in Peru on your way to somewhere, but where is that? Or is your question whether you can get yourself onto a plane bound for Peru by having a connecting ticket that you don't plan to use, and then throw yourself at the mercy of the Peruvian boarder guards when you arrive because you don't have the required visa? That's highly unlikely to end well ...

Comment: what about "I am starting to consider an alternative to Peru". I booked the ticket already so I don't want it to go wasted. I juste think about booking another ticket such that my trip looks like Germany-Lima-Some Country-Lima-Germany where I don't go out of the airport in Lima, thus my question about the visa requirements in case one wants to transit only

Comment: x @Mehdi: Please explain in greater detail what you mean by that. What does "an alternative" mean for you?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have an onward ticket from Lima, you don't need a visa for transit <24 hours:

> ￼
>   Peru (PE) ￼ TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets 
>   for a max. transit For details, click here time of 24 hours.There is no hotel accommodation available at Lima Airport.

According to Timatic (The system the airlines use at check in to see if you're eligible to board) you're good

Comment: Thanks, didn't come to my mind to check Timatic. Airport websites really offer poor information about this kind of things.

Comment: Yeah they do, thats why its always good to check Timatic yourself :)